# Regex Help, anti-query replacement

Tags: regex

How do I remove any lines that have 3 or less slashes, but retain bigger links?

```
A. http://two/three/four
B. http://two/three
C. http://two
```

A would stay nothing else would.

Thanks

Comment: FYI Added demo and explanation. Let me know if you have any questions. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Search: `(?m)^(?:[^/]*/){0,3}[^/]*$`

Replace: `""`

On the [demo](http://regex101.com/r/rA4gB3), see how only the lines with 3 or fewer slashes are matched. These are the ones to nix.

**Explain Regex**

```
(?m)                     # set flags for this block (with ^ and $
                         # matching start and end of line) (case-
                         # sensitive) (with . not matching \n)
                         # (matching whitespace and # normally)
^                        # the beginning of a "line"
(?:                      # group, but do not capture (between 0 and 3
                         # times (matching the most amount
                         # possible)):
  [^/]*                  #   any character except: '/' (0 or more
                         #   times (matching the most amount
                         #   possible))
  /                      #   '/'
){0,3}                   # end of grouping
[^/]*                    # any character except: '/' (0 or more times
                         # (matching the most amount possible))
$                        # before an optional \n, and the end of a
                         # "line"
```

Comment: That's making my head hurt.. but it works. Thanks. I also found something like:
`^((?!https://blah/.*/).)*$`

Comment: @lakecityransom You're welcome. :) Hey, since I see you haven't yet posted an upvote on SO, please consider voting up any answers you find useful (thanks for listening to my 10-second SO tut :)

Answer (score 1):

## `sed`

You can use following `sed` command to do that, assuming your lines are in `foo.txt`:

```
sed -n '/\(.*\/\)\{4,\}/p' foo.txt
```

The `-n` option is for no output, but lines matching the pattern between the `/`s are printed anyway thanks to the `p` command at the end of the `sed` expression.

The pattern is: at least 4 occurences of `/`, each one potentially preceeded by any other string.

Comment: Aww… I didn't know that. I'm glad you have an answer that works then :) I hope mine can be useful to someone else.